# Ubuntu desktop VNC server like Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I've looked and looked and I can't find instructions on how to set up VNC server on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop so that I can remote in just like when I was running Windows.

I use my computer at work most days of the week, but I want to log in from home and display it exactly as I left it. All of the instructions I find leave me with a blank shell, not what I left running at work. How can I get it to function more or less like Remote Desktop in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `vnc4server`?

https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/

Probably works fine on Ubuntu Desktop.

If not, check this one out.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/

Comment: The first one doesn't share my existing desktop, it creates a new one. The second doesn't work in 14.04.